# Accessing broadcast variables in user defined function (udf) in separate files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, broadcast

I have broadcast variable setup in a separate py file and I am then importing the same in a file that contains my UDFs. But when I try to use this variable in UDF, I see that broadcast variable is not initialized (NoneType) when used in the scope of some `Dataframe` transformation function. Here is the supporting code.

Broadcast model is in `utils.py` and defined as below,

```
class Broadcaster(object):
    _map = {}
    _bv = None

    @staticmethod
    def set_item(k, v):
        Broadcaster._map[k] = v

    @staticmethod
    def broadcast(sc):
        Broadcaster._bv = sc.broadcast(Broadcaster._map)

    @staticmethod
    def get_item(k):
        val = Broadcaster._bv.value
        return val.get(k)
```

Reason for doing this is to provide an interface where multiple k,v combinations can be set before broadcasting. Which means, in my `main.py`, I can now call `Broadcaster.set_item(k, v)` multiple times and then eventually call `Broadcaster.broadcast(sc)` which is working fine. But now, I want to use this broadcast variable in UDF which is in a separate file (say `udfs.py`). Note that these UDFs are used in my `Dataframe` processing. Below is a sample UDF,

```
def my_udf(col):
    bv = Broadcaster._bv.value    #this throws exception :-(
    #more code
```

In my `udfs.py` file, I have no trouble accessing `Broadcaster._bv.value`. Just that when used within udf and when this udf is called from within `Dataframe`, I am getting `NoneType` doesn't have `value` exception. Basically worker nodes are unable to access broadcasted variable. Why can't I use the broadcast variable in cross files? I have seen examples where people are defining udf in the same file where broadcasted variable is present and it seem to be working fine. But I need to have these in separate files due to the volume of code. What are my options?

**EDIT:** I don't want to serialize the object, pass it to UDF during call and de-serialize within UDF. I believe that defeats the purpose of broadcast variable.